# Nature doco sound design?

Tags: documentary, nature, field-recording, sound-design

I'm just curious to ask anyone who has produced sound for a nature documentary, how much of the audio content is recorded in the field or how much is the product of sound design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, generally a very large percentage of audio in nature docs is recorded in post. Back in January I posted a TVB Europe magazine article on [my blog](http://audioloungesound.com/blog/2011/01/the-sounds-of-nature/) that deals with exactly that subject.

Comment: That is a fantastic article, thanks @Colin! This issue was exactly what was on my mind when I asked this one: http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/2090/what-is-our-responsibility-to-authenticity

Answer (score 3):

I know some people who work in that arena and from the stories I've been told that it's a frighteningly large amount... or more than the suits would like us admitting to. I'd say at least 75% in most situations.

Comment: It's a good thing for sound designers though! I would be very interested in doing this sort of 'nature' sound design at some stage in my career.

Comment: I suppose, if you're always on point enough to always remain transparent and make the best choices in some dicey situations (like replacing animal sounds with different animals) and keep it believable all the time. I can imagine it's rewarding, but stressful. *Or I'm too OCD for a position like that (most likely). 